# Hiding the element Using negative left position in chrome.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

When I hide an absolute positioned element by setting the left value in negative(the left will be the negative value of its width).

Its hidden, and it does not impact its successive (next) elements in all the browsers except Chrome. In chrome this negative positioned element occupies some 1 to 2 px of space in its position and pushes the other (successive) elements to 1 or 2 px away.

If i set display none(instead of negative position), It can be resolved. But i do some other manipulations based on its visibility.

If any one know solution for this problem, Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In stackoverflow we provide some code, generaly on a jsfiddle, can you do this ?

Comment: random thought.... Its not a border or something?? as in,, say width of 100px with a 1px border... This would give you a true width of 102px..... But in short, position:absolute; should not affect any other element except for its children... Otherwise you could try using "visibility: hidden;"